# How to notify a moderator of list of question where a bulk retagging would be appropriate?

Tags: support, tags, moderation, serial-edits

**My case:**

I am a delphi enthusiast. I discovered that many questions dealing with **frame** are just barely tagged with [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) and should be also tagged with [tframe](/questions/tagged/tframe).

**My question:**

Batch/Bulk retagging being a moderator-only function, is it possible to submit a list of question where a new tag is to be applied?

Answer (score 6):

Unless all the questions with one tag should be tagged with another tag *instead*, this isn't something moderators have a tool for.  If you give us a list of questions, we'd have to go through them one at a time, like anyone else.

If you can come up with a search link or a general rule you might post it here on Meta and ask for help with a massive retagging from the community.

Answer (score 5):

There is no batch or bulk retagging, even for moderators. The only tool of that kind is the merge tool to merge two tags into one. Devs, but not moderators, can also completely erase a tag.

You'll have to apply the tag manually to all of those questions.